# Pagedlistadapter return no item in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-pagedlistview

I am trying to use `PagedListAdapter` to a custom `RecyclerView`, ([link here](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView)).

In my `ViewModel`, when observing the data retrieved with `Observer(adapter::submitList)` no item is shown.

When debugging this line:

```
productViewModel.allProducts.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))
```

I saw that a `TiledPagedList` object has my items / see picture ->
[Debugging Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT9mW.png)

In my repository class:

```
fun getProductsFromDb(): LiveData<PagedList<Product>> {
        return LivePagedListBuilder(productDao.getProducts(), 20).build()
    }
```

In my `ViewModel` class:

```
allProducts = repository.getProducts()
```

In my `Activity` class:

```
adapter = CardStackAdapter()
        productViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductViewModel::class.java)
        productViewModel.allProducts.observe(this, Observer(adapter::submitList))
productViewModel.allProducts.value?.dataSource?.invalidate()
//productViewModel .allProducts.observe(this, PagedList(adapter::submitList))
```

How can I apply correctly the items retrieved from my db to my `recyclerView`? (Apply what I see on `TiledPagedList` object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My error was to override getItemCount() in my adapter class and to get the size of a list in parameter that was not used.